# calculate homography to generate a bird's eye view image

Tags: computer-vision, homography

I have a 3D point $(x_w,y_w,z_w)$ with normals $(X_n,Y_n,Z_n)$, with the intrinsic matrix I can project it to image space $(x_i,y_i)$. I want to calculate a homography matrix such that I know how the 2D feature around $x_i,y_i$ looks like when it is located at the center of the image, as well as correcting any perspective error and here is my approach:

First I calculate the 3x3 rotation matrix ($R$) to transform $X_n,Y_n,Z_n$ to $0,0,1$ so that the 3D normals is facing towards the camera. Then I come out with this equation.

```
 image width / 2                       r11 r12 tx  
 image height /2  = intrinsic matrix * r21 r22 ty * intrinsic matrix.inverse()
        1                              r31 r32 tz
```

r11,r12,r21,r22,r31,r32 comes from the R rotation matrix, i know the intrinsic matrix and the image size, so all I have to do is to solve for tx,ty,tz. After solving it the right side of the equation will be my homography matrix.

Just wondering if this is a correct approach?